# Deploy Docker Image to Heroku : H14 Error

Tags: docker, heroku

So I tried to deploy my pre-created docker image to heroku. I followed the tutorial in this link : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#using-a-ci-cd-platform

I followed each step until "release the image to your app". Then I tried to open the created app on the heroku dashboard and it showed

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application 
owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

and when I checked the log :

```
Error H14 (No web processes running)
```

Can somebody help me? I'm new to heroku, thanks!

Comment: Do you have any dynos running?

Comment: @Y.S. I'm not sure, how do I check?

Comment: Using Heroku CLI, you can type `heroku ps`, which lists all dynos for the app. Or you can also check on your app overview or resources page.